# How can I access a minimized form from another form without creating an instance?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

In my winforms application I am using form.ActiveForm from another form a lot of times. This is because I don't want a new instance of the form but just to bring the form to the front or to set it's components differently. I noticed however that when I minimize the form, form.ActiveForm returns a NullReferenceException. What can I do so that I can access this minimized form? There doesn't seem to be a method for it. Is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Application.OpenForms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.openforms.aspx) to find a form of the correct type:

```
foreach (var f in Application.OpenForms)
{
    if (f is MyForm)
    {
        // do something...
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: I found this as a better solution. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Store the minimized form as a field in your primary form, and access it that way.  If the form is minimized, then it is not "active."  Using the field, you will still be able to access it, however.

Answer (score 0):

Save a reference to the minimized form. If you like, you can store it with the second form by creating a public property:

```
public MyForm myForm;
```

And then set it:

```
MyForm frm = new MyForm();
frm.myForm = (first form reference here);
```

And then the second form can directly reference the first form using `myForm`.

Comment: Yes this makes sense.. but what if I don't even have a reference to that myForm from frm? Do I keep setting the form to different forms?

Comment: Probably better you have a class called FormManager with a `List<Form>`

Comment: @Bernice: I'm not sure what you mean by "keep setting the form to different forms". Just set it to the instance of your form. (How many are there?) You need to store the reference one way or another, I just suggested one way you could do that. You cannot access an existing form without storing a reference to that form somewhere.